# Arial black suddenly not working in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I noticed today that a site I developed has suddenly stopped rendering the "Arial Black" font face in chrome.

Does anyone know if any recent Chrome updates could have caused "arial black" to stop working?

Even the example on w3schools has stopped working in chrome: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It comes set by default with the latest Chrome update (Version 37.x) (Originally on Chrome 35 beta and not set by default) and it's how Chrome uses the `DirectWrite` API on Windows to  render the font.

If you want the old behavior open `chrome://flags/` and enable `Disable DirectWrite`.

This will disable the use of experimental `DirectWrite` font rendering system.

Also as noted in [this bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=366983):

> This all comes from DW treating font weights as different variations
>   of the same font, unlike GDI. Thus Arial Black is considered to be
>   Arial with a weight of 900 and that matches the specified family.

So if "Arial Black" falls back to "Arial" with a weight of 900 and weight of 900 in Arial is not the same 'weight' as Arial Black, then you will see the difference in the rendered font.

Comment: Is the DirectWrite font rendering the "fix" for the fact that previous versions of Chrome couldn't anti-alias text correctly? Trying to figure out if disabling it will do me more harm than good.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Yes, it seems that's how they are addressing that particular issue.

Comment: It’s not “how Chrome renders the font”. Chrome does not render it *at all*. You can see this by testing with `font-family: "Arial Black", Courier`.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela DirectWrite is a Windows API that Chrome uses to render fonts. I updated the answer to be more clear. http://blog.chromium.org/2014/07/chrome-37-beta-directwrite-on-windows.html

Comment: @Arbel, it’s still not a matter of rendering “the font” (but possibly of font rendering in general). If the analysis were correct, then setting `font-family: Arial; font-weight: 900` would result in Arial Black to be used; but it results in Arial Bold.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela It results in falling back to Arial and trying to use the weight 900 (which apparently is not working for any reason) so the closest one, 700, same as Arial Bold is used.

Answer (score 0):

In my case enable `Disable DirectWrite` doesn't solve the problem.

I figured out [here](http://smuggbugg.com/fix-helvetica-neue-font-issue-chrome/#axzz3iUYcZKQp) that the problem actually was not only in the font **Arial Black** but **Helvetica Neue**.

Simply edit:

C:\Users[YourName]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\User StyleSheets\custom.css

and add the two code given below

```
@font-face { font-family: ‘helvetica neue’; src: local(‘Arial’); }
@font-face { font-family: ‘helvetica neue’; font-weight:bold; src: local(‘Arial’); }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Use arial black or arial narrow. 
Example: 
font_formats: "Andale Mono=andale mono,times;"+
        "Arial=arial narrow,avant garde;"+
        "Arial Black=arial black,avant garde;"+
        "Courier New=courier new,courier;"+
        "Georgia=georgia,palatino;"+
        "Impact=impact,chicago;"+
        "Symbol=symbol;"+
        "Tahoma=tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"+
        "Times New Roman=times new roman,times;"+
        "Verdana=verdana,geneva;"+
        "Webdings=webdings;"+
        "Wingdings=wingdings,zapf dingbats",
```